# use jquery selector with variable failed in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var x = 1
$('#item+x .list').remove();
```

how to insert x into selector? above code doesn't work, I also tried $('#item"'x'" .list')..

Comment: regular string concatenation -> `$('#item'+x+' .list').remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adeneo and Vijay are both right on for how to do what you asked.

One thing I would mention is that, IMO, using incremental ids (`item1`, `item2`, etc...) is bad practice and you can end up with some pretty messy code.

For something like this, I would prefer to give all the elements a single class instead of incremental ids and use `eq()` to target the elements. Just remember that `eq:()` works off a 0 based array concept so `eq:(0)` will target the first element, `eq:(1)` will target the second, etc...

Here is a contrived example:

```js
var x = 1
$('.items:eq('+x+') .list').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list 1</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div class="items">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list 2</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div class="items">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list 3</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div class="items">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list 4</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div class="items">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>list 5</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope it will help

```js
var x = 1;
$('#item' + x + ' .list').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use also attach a class and use 
    $(this).remove() 
instead.

You can also extend to the parent if you want to delete the parent container with
    $(this).parent().remove()

Example :

```
<ul>
  <li class="item">Item1</li>
  <li class="item">Item2</li>
</ul>
```

Then using Jquery:

```
$('.item').click(function() {
   $(this).remove();
})
```